# SQL, Assign Select Column to Variable

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012, I am going to Create Store Procedure which copies a column from a table in a variable, Could any one please tell me what is Wrong with this code?

```
  alter Procedure Id_Fetch
  @Col varchar(50)=null,
  @Table VARCHAR(50)=Null,
  @OrdrBy Varchar(40)=null
 as 
 Begin
declare @TempCol nvarchar (100)
Exec(' SELECT '+@TempCol+' = '+@Col+' from ' + @Table +' order by '+@OrdrBy )
```

its showing error "Incorrect Syntax near '='

Comment: Print out the statement you're trying to execute, that certainly doesn't look like valid sql to me.

Comment: I don't suppose I could convince you that this is an extraordinarily bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little modification ...... Use TOP 1 in your select as if more than one value is returned by your select it will throw an error.

Use `SYSNAME` datatype for your Column names and table names.

Use `QUOTENAME()` function around your object name parameters, which puts square brackets `[]` around the passed parameter value and forces it to be treated as an object name (Protection against Sql Injection attack).

Use `sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC` and concatenating parameter values into string and executing again protects you  against Sql Injection attack.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Id_Fetch
   @Col         SYSNAME,
   @Table       SYSNAME,
   @OrdrBy      SYSNAME,
   @Col_Value   NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql =  N' SELECT TOP 1 @Col_Value = ' + QUOTENAME(@Col) 
            + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) 
            + N' ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@OrdrBy)  

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                       ,N'@Col_Value  NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT'
                       ,@Col_Value OUTPUT

END
```